# How can I get the S/N of my laptop display screen?

Tags: laptop, display

Thanks for spending time to read my concern. How to get serial number of laptop display screen? I am facing "White screen" issue with my laptop screen. I have checked with external display (LED TV) and it works fine. So, mostly problem is not with graphic card, but it is with display screen. Local repair shop vendor suggested to change display screen. So, just to be sure they are giving me new screen, I want to compare old and new serial numbers after they replace it.

I am not pro in PC or computer, but can certainly handle CMD command. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no method of getting the serial number of the display panel from the operating system.

In order to get the serial number and model of the LCD panel itself, you would need to disassemble the laptop and remove the panel.  LCD manufacturers generally put the model and serial number on a sticker on the rear of the panel.

Comment: Some displays might be able to display this information, the same way they display the configuration information (brightness, color, input mode, etc), but that is a function of the display, not the OS.  There are standards that would cover sending this information but what information is or isn't sent by the display to the host machine is depends entirely on the connection (HDMI, DisplayPort, ect).